# Using wc on a file while it is used by other program

Tags: linux, filesystems

I am generating a text file that in the end will contain roughly a billion entries. The file is generated by a program that writes to it every couple of seconds. For this it always opens the file and then closes it, so the file is not kept open in write mode all the time. Since this whole process takes a long time I would like to execute 'wc -l < file_name' to see how many entries are already there (one entry = one line).

But I am wondering is if this is a bad idea? Since wc needs a couple a minutes to count all the lines, it will read the file while my program writes to it. I don't care if there are minor discrepancies between the number of lines counted by wc and the actual number of lines. It's more that I am worried that my program won't be able to write the data to the file.

Can that happen on my Linux system?

Answer (score 2):

This is usually accomplished by means of *locks*. There are two kinds of *locks* in Linux, advisory and mandatory.

Advisory locks require cooperation between competing processes, *i.e.*, that each process first check whether a lock exists on the file, then acts according to its existence (=wait) or non-existence (=read/write). Mandatory locking instead gives one process the authority to inhibit the other processes from acting on the locked file.

You did not state what kind of process is writing to your large file, so I do not know which of these two alternatives is most suitable. I may suggest a [good Intro](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/linux-file-locking-types/) to the topic, for lack of more information.

Comment: The process that writes to my file is a python script that does the most simple thing: It creates a list of points, and whenever this list gets too large it writes its contents to the file. For this the usual Python commands are used. In particular it doesn't pay any attention to locks or something like this. When it's done writing it closes the file again.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert on the details of how file handles are managed but off the top of my head I seen no reason to have a problem here. As long as programA is *writing* and programB is *reading*, there should be no issues.

While you may of course have inconsistent results in the `wc` output, I don't see how you could have corrupted data written to the file just because you read it. If you had two programs *writing* to the same file, that would have been a different matter.

So, locks are indeed the best way to deal with overlapping file access but they should not be needed if all you are doing is using `wc` to monitor progress. I have done the same thousands of times with no problem. You might, however, consider either adding a progress meter printing to standard error to your script or using `tail -f` on the generated file.

Comment: I already suspected that it probably is not problematic. But I was wondering what would happen in the unlikely event that wc reads the end of the file while my program tries to append the next batch to the end. I like your idea of how to realize a progress meter.

Comment: @Gregor what I usually do is i) print the current line number to stderr if `$line % 100 == 0` or so ii) watch the file's size with `ls -l` iii) use `tail -f` or iv) use `wc -l` as you do. If `wc` accesses the file just as the next line is written, then if the last new line has been printed, `wc` will count it and, if not, it won't. Either way, no problem.